# convert js promise chain to synchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, promise, puppeteer

I have this code that basically iterates over an array of URL, and for each URL, calls the page and performs some task on the resulting HTML.

But I want the code to be completely synchronous, i.e. I want to execute all the steps sequentially:
launch the browser, get the page, use the content.

I don't understand how to do that.

I'm trying to convert to async function and using await, but  I can't make it work

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const urlList = ["http://example.com","http://demo.com"]
for (let i = 0; i< urlList.length; i++) {
  let pageContent = puppeteer
                    .launch()
                    .then(function(browser) {
                         return browser.newPage();
                    })
                   .then(function(page) {
                                    return page.goto(urlList[i])
                                               .then(function() {
                                                   return page.content();
                                                   });
                          })
                   .then(function(html){
                              //do something with html
                              console.log(html.length);
                         })
                   .catch(function(err) {
                                             //handle error
                                   });

}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to show us your attempt at await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make your function synchronous (well, actually you can do it in Node.js using the `deasync` npm package but it's a bad practice and often it doesn't make sense). But you can convert your code to async/await:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const urlList = ["http://example.com","http://demo.com"]
(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i< urlList.length; i++) {
    try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(urlList[i]);
      const html = await page.content();
      // do something with html
      console.log(html);
    } catch (err) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
})();
```

As you can see, you also have to wrap your code into an `async` function. I have used an IIFE, but you can make it a separate function and reuse it anywhere in your code.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion myself. Is it true that there is still one async function (the wrapper) but all the requests are called in sequence, that's what I meant with synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace each `then` with an `await`:

```js
async function myFunction()
{
  try
  {
     let browser =  await puppeteer.launch();
     let page = await browser.newPage();
     await page.goto(urlList[i]);
     let html = page.content();
     // ...etc
  }
  catch
  {
     //handle error
  }
}
```

also bear in mind that this must bye called inside of an `async` function.

Also this is **NOT synchronous**. This simply flattens the promise chain. It still runs asynchronous. You cannot make an async function synchronous. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: basically the same solution as the accepted one, but the accepted one works right away. In your code, I guess I have to call myFunction() to make it work. But yes, what I wanted to do was exactly to "flatten the promise chain". thx